# why does annotate class as @Service do not create bean?

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, ejb

I has class like this:

```
@Service("userDetailsService") 
public class MyUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {
    ...
```

and trying to do:

```
<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService">
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

and I got followin errors:

> Cannot resolve reference to bean 'userDetailsService' while setting
>   bean property 'userDetailsService'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   bean named 'userDetailsService' is defined

Is it really necessary to declare bean? In that case like this:

```
<beans:bean id="myUserDetailsService" class="my.package.services.MyUserDetailsService" />
```

**EDIT**

Here is my `security.xml` file:

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd">

    <http>
        <form-login login-page="/login/"
            authentication-failure-url="/fail/" />
        <logout logout-success-url="/" />
    </http>

    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="my.package" />

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="myUserDetailsService">
            <!-- <password-encoder hash="md5" /> -->
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

which cause:

> The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for
>   element 'context:annotation-config'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing schema location for context.

So your xml should start with:

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">
```

Answer (score 4):

If you use annotations to specify your beans, you need to have add an entry to your config to [scan the classpath](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html#beans-classpath-scanning) for them.

```
<context:component-scan base-package="org.example"/>
```

Comment: Thx, I has that one line but not in my `security.xml` file... but even after add it, there is still some problem, plz check edit

Answer (score 1):

`@Service` extends `@Component` which allows for `classpath scanning`.

You can enable both `classpath scanning` and `annotations`

```
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.package.a,com.b" />
```

I don't know what version are you using. Try this.

```
<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService">
        <!-- <password-encoder hash="md5" /> -->
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

Unless you provide, as you do, a name, it will be the class name. But you provide the same name it would be but stating another in the config file.

If you `@Service` with no name then it would be fine.

Comment: Thx, I has that one line but not in my `security.xml` file... but even after add it, there is still some problem, plz check edit

Answer (score 1):

just import the other xml file in the spring-security.xml by using `<beans:import resource="" />`

another thing u can do is that load all the xml files in the web.xml file using

```
<context-param>
<param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
<param-value>
path to the xml files separated by commas
</param-value>
</context-param>
```