# spring security bean not found exception

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm trying to set up spring security for an mvc project, and I'm having a hard time. I'm using the spring security 3.1.4.Release. I have a spring-security.xml file set up along with and mvc-dispatcher-servlet file set up for configuration. Right now I'm getting a bean not found exception for my User Details Bean.

In intellij I get a "cannot resolve bean" message for the myUserDetailService. I also cannot resolve the package "controller". The root error when I run the project is:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'myUserDetailService' while setting bean property 'userDetailsService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'myUserDetailService' is defined
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:329) [spring-beans-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:107) [spring-beans-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
```

Here is my spring-security.xml file:

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
         xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
         xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">


<!-- Enabling Spring beans auto-discovery -->
   <context:component-scan base-package="controller, com.company.admin" />

<http auto-config="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/admin/*" access="ROLE_USER"  />
    <form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/admin/welcome"   authentication-failure-url="/loginfailed" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/logout" />
</http>

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="myUserDetailService"/>
</authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

Here is my mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">


<!-- Enabling Spring beans auto-discovery -->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.company.admin" />

<!-- Enabling Spring MVC configuration through annotations -->
<mvc:annotation-driven />

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
</beans>
```

Here is my web.xml:

```
<web-app version="2.4"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

<display-name>Spring MVC Application</display-name>


<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml,
        /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>
</web-app>
```

I'm basically trying to follow this tutorial: http://kh-yiu.blogspot.com/2012/12/spring-mvc-security-custom.html and the UserDetailServiceImpl is pretty identical to that, but I do have it in a different folder in my main/java directory. It's important to note I use annotations to declare the class:

```
@Service("myUserDetailService")
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService{
```

Any ideas? I'm having a very hard time finding tutorials with the same spring version that I'm using, so it's quite possible I've messed up xsd refs. Thanks.

Comment: Make your `component-scan` packages more restrictive. They are currently overwriting each other.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by making them more restrictive. If they are overwriting each other would I just put it in one of the context files?

Comment: Each of your contexts is scanning the same package in the `component-scan`. So each one will create beans. Each context should only scan packages that are related to their purpose.

Comment: Ahh... your suggestions caused me to dig into the package name and found I had an issue on where the UserDetails file was located. Careless oversight on my part. I just solved the problem by fixing the name. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding a reference to:

```
<authentication-provider user-service-ref="myUserDetailService"/>
```

You need a bean with that id.. something like:

```
<bean id="myUserDetailService" class="the.class.of.your.service"></bean>
```

Just break a bit your exception:

```
//Error creating the bean
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider#0': 
//The myUserDetailService reference cannot be solved, it cannot be found or it has syntax error or something is wrong there
Cannot resolve reference to bean 'myUserDetailService' while setting bean property 'userDetailsService'; 
//The root cause is an exception deeper.
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: 
//You don't have a bean with this name:
No bean named 'myUserDetailService' is defined
```

Updated:

Now that you added the @Service myUserDetailService... it may be a duplicated of [why does annotate class as @Service do not create bean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8173009/why-does-annotate-class-as-service-do-not-create-bean)

Comment: I'm not saying you are wrong, but what makes you think there isn't such a bean created because of `component-scan`.

Comment: The service file is declared with an annotation. I could include that in the question. @Service("myUserDetailService")
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService{

Comment: Your suggestion led me down the right path because I had to reevaluate the package path, which was wrong. Silly mistake on my part, but thanks for your help. :)