# Annotation not working in spring

Tags: java, spring

i am a beginner in spring ,i have a dao class in spring .but annotation @ auto wired or @ service is not working ,i have solved the issue by creating a bean in application context,what is the reason for annotation not working in spring .provided with "context:component-scan base-package=" also but annotations are not working

```
      StudentDao

     public interface StudentDao {
      public int addStudent(StudentEntity s);
    }
  -----------------------------------
  @Service("studentDaoImpl")
   public class StudentDaoImpl implements StudentDao{
   @PersistenceContext
   private EntityManager em;
   @Override
   @Transactional
    public int addStudent(StudentEntity student) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    em.persist(student);
    return student.getId();
   }
}
   ------------------------------------------------
FascadeDaoImpl
public class FascadeControllerImpl implements FascadeController {
//  @Autowired
private StudentDao studentDao;
private UserContext uc;

public void studentDao() {
    studentDao=(StudentDao) uc.getContext().getBean("studentDao");

    }
 }

 public int addStudent(StudentEntity student) {
    studentDao();
    return studentDao.addStudent(student);
}
```

ApplicationContext

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" 
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" 
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="sms.spring.dao" />
<context:component-scan base-package="sms.spring.fascade" />
<context:component-scan base-package="sms.spring.entity" />
<context:annotation-config />


<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>
<bean class="sms.spring.entity.StudentEntity" id="studentbean"/>
<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName">
        <value>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</value>
    </property>
    <property name="url">
        <value>jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=dbstsms</value>
    </property>
    <property name="username">
        <value>sa</value>
    </property>
    <property name="password">
        <value>sa123</value>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:META-INF/persistence.xml" />
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="PERSUnit" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
    </property>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="fascadeController" class="sms.spring.fascade.FascadeControllerImpl"></bean>
<bean id="studentDao" class="sms.spring.dao.StudentDaoImpl"></bean>
<bean id="loginDao" class="sms.spring.dao.LoginDaoImpl"></bean>
<bean id="facultyDao" class="sms.spring.dao.FacultyDaoImpl"></bean>
<bean id="markDao" class="sms.spring.dao.MarkDaoImpl"></bean>
<bean id="notificationDao" class="sms.spring.dao.NotificationDaoImpl"></bean>
<tx:annotation-driven />
```

Comment: "Not working" is not a working description of a problem that we could help with.

Comment: You are trying to mix xml based configuration along with annotations. Its also possible, but you need to take care of things.

It's hard to guess the problem with your code, because you didn't shared all the configurations.

I'll suggest either use only xml based configuration or annotation based configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please post the error that you are getting,Also from the code you have posted I can see that even though you have annotated the StudentDaoImpl class with @service annotation you are again defining the same in the xml configuration,Kindly use either annotation based config or xml based configuration.

Please check if your file has

1. `<context:annotation-config/>` is mentioned in the xml config(Not needed if component scan is enabled)
2. Check if component scan  is enabled for the package
3. Please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8173009/why-does-annotate-class-as-service-do-not-create-bean) answer for the correct schema location

Comment: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'fascadebean': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private sms.spring.dao.StudentDaoImpl sms.spring.fascade.FascadeControllerImpl.studentDaoImpl; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionExcept‌​ion: No qualifying bean of type [sms.spring.dao.StudentDaoImpl] found for dependency:

Comment: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(req‌​uired=true) @Optimus

Comment: Just realized that you are searching for bean with name `studentDao` but in the annotation based config you have given the bean name as studentDaoImpl, Since the annotation based config overrides the xml based config you might be hitting this issue,Can you change     `studentDao=(StudentDao) uc.getContext().getBean("studentDao");`
to     'studentDao=(StudentDao) uc.getContext().getBean("studentDaoImpl");`

Comment: still error is same i could acess bean if i specify it in xml configuration,is the any possible way to make my annotation to work  @Optimus

Comment: `<context:annotation-config /> ` is missing.Might be the cause why your annotation config is not working, Also if you are using annotation config remove it from xml

Comment: tried sample using <context:annotation-config /> still error is repeating what is the reason for annotation not working?@Optimus

Comment: for annotation config to work you need three things firstly the xml should have `<context:annotation-config />` then the component scan must be enabled in the xml and the package should be pointing to the package of the class file, then @Service notation should be present, if these things are there ideally it should work

Comment: Also check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8173009/why-does-annotate-class-as-service-do-not-create-bean) answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133978/discussion-between-optimus-and-ann).

Answer (score 1):

Question is not clear, but it looks like your controller should also be annotated with `@Controller`. All classes belonging to a Spring project that have autowired dependencies, need to be created by Spring. In short, you should never make a `new` of a Spring class and create them using the `ApplicationContext#getBean()` or when it gets injected by another class.

Moreover, bear in mind with the constructors as at the point of creation of the bean the autowired dependencies are null (not initialized) and you need to create an `init()` method annotated with `@PostConstruct`.

Answer (score 1):

Two main causes are:

1. You must tell spring, where to scan your components (make sure the packages are right)
2. You don't have an implementation of an actual bean (make sure StudentDao have @Service too)