# Spring-do we need to specify the bean in xml if we use annotation

Tags: java, spring

Spring-do we need to specify the bean in xml if we use annotation,is there any need of using a bean id in xml if we use annotation @aurowired

```
public class TextEditor {
  @Autowired
  private SpellChecker spellChecker;
  public TextEditor() {
     System.out.println("Inside TextEditor constructor." );
  }
  public SpellChecker getSpellChecker( ){
     return spellChecker;
  }
  public void spellCheck(){
     spellChecker.checkSpelling();
  }
}
```

application context

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

 <context:annotation-config/>

 <!-- Definition for textEditor bean without constructor-arg  -->
 <bean id="textEditor" class="com.tutorialspoint.TextEditor">
 </bean>

 <!-- Definition for spellChecker bean -->
 <bean id="spellChecker" class="com.tutorialspoint.SpellChecker">
 </bean>

</beans>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To define a managed bean, you either

- define it in XML
- use `@Component` or `@Service` annotation on the bean's class and appropriate `context:component-scan` in XML

To use it, you either

- declare the dependency in XML
- use @Autowired annotation

If you want to use any of the annotations, you need `context:annotation-config` in XML.

You only need to assign an ID to the bean if you want to refer to it by that ID, be it in XML or in the `@Qualifier` annotation when autowiring.

Comment: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'fascadebean': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private sms.spring.dao.StudentDaoImpl sms.spring.fascade.FascadeControllerImpl.studentDaoImpl; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionExcept‌​ion: No qualifying bean of type [sms.spring.dao.StudentDaoImpl] found for dependency:

Comment: is there any possible solution to get rid of this error tried context:annotation-config @Jiri Tousek

Comment: How is your `StudentDaoImpl` instance defined? XML or an annotation (which annotation)? Do you have both `annotation-config` and `component-scan` presentin your XML? what packages does the latter scan?

Comment: i have a dao interface and an implementation class annoted with service and the design patern is fascade and in fascadeImpl i have declared a daoClass with autowiring its property and an error is ploating as above i have used context:component-scan is there any possible solution @Jiri Tousek

Comment: Put all relevant code as an edit to the question, this way we can't see what you have.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41673812/annotation-not-working-in-spring question already asked @Jiri Tousek

Answer (score 2):

There will be no need to declare each and every bean in your application context.You can use component-scan and provide your base package containing all beans.

```
<context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.package" />
```

And use `@Service` tag for each class which you want to autowire.

Answer (score 1):

Add component-scan to the XML with the package and Annotate both `TextEditor` and `SpellChecker` with `@Component` at the top.

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.tutorialspoint" />
```

Then you don't need to Define any bean on the XML file.

Comment: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'fascadebean': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private sms.spring.dao.StudentDaoImpl sms.spring.fascade.FascadeControllerImpl.studentDaoImpl; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [sms.spring.dao.StudentDaoImpl] found for dependency:

Comment: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)

Comment: i have a dao interface and an implementation class annoted with @service  and the design patern is fascade and in fascadeImpl

Comment: i have declared a daoClass with autowiring its property and an error is ploating as above i have used context:component-scan is there any possible solution  @shazin

Answer (score 1):

@aurowired  by default auto wires bean by type. if you use

```
<bean  class="com.tutorialspoint.SpellChecker"> 
</bean>
```

This will work as spring injects bean by type.
But if your are creating 2 beans

```
<bean id ="spell1" class="com.tutorialspoint.SpellChecker">
 </bean>
<bean id ="spell2" class="com.tutorialspoint.SpellChecker">
 </bean>
```

This will not work as there are two beans of same type. You have to use @qualifier.